# error --Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Tags: chunked-encoding

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

I am getting above error in browser console in between my php script.
The script starts but hang in between, there is no error as far as coding is concerned. I am calling php user define functions after input two dates. i even try to input single date but of no avail.
The problem persists in chrome as well as explorer and even try on another computer.

I chat with server helpdesk and they run the same program at their end. The error they told is as below:

(70007) The timeout specified has expired:ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed

Please suggest.
Thanks

Comment: You have to increase the timeout, or query less data in less time.